# React Redux Confirmation action box error: Application state or actions payloads are too large

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

Hi I am trying to create a simple popup box showing a validation Text and input field, the user needs to insert some text into the input for confirmation, then click "Confirm" appon clicking confirm a function will be executed.

the confirmation component will receive this props:
isOpen - boolean,
msg - string,
executableFunction - function

this three props will be received via Redux Store because this component is shared by many other components I placed it at my app.js file.

I tested it in a small example and it works, but when I tried to implement it for real I got this error: 
"
VM594 react_devtools_backend.js:6 Application state or actions payloads are too large making Redux DevTools serialization slow and consuming a lot of memory. See https://git.io/fpcP5 on how to configure it.
"

I imagine the executable function is too big, its a function that make a http post request to a server gets a response back and make changes to a component (basically show to the user the result of the execution...).

is there a way around this problem ? what am I doing wrong ?

the confirmation component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { setConfirmation } from '../../../actions/sharedComponentsAction';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { toastr } from "react-redux-toastr";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';
import {handleChange} from "../../functionUtils/FunctionsUtils";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    modal: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    paper: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        border: '2px solid #000',
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
        padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
    },
    textField: {
        width: '400px',
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(6),
    },
    button: {
        width: 120,
    },
}));

const ConfirmationPopupValidateXXX = ({ selectedClient, setConfirmation, isOpen ,message, validationHelperText, executableFunction }) => {
    const { XXX } = selectedClient.value;

    const [InputtedXXX, setInputtedXXX] = useState('');

    const handleClose = async () => {
        await console.log('handleClose Called');
        await setConfirmation(false);
    };

    const validateAndExecuteFunction = () => {
        console.log('validateAndExecuteFunction called');

        if ( XXX !== InputtedXXX )
        {
            toastr.error('XXX Name Doesnt Equal Selecte Client\'s XXX');
            return;
        }

        executableFunction();

        handleClose();
    };

    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div>
            <Modal
                aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
                aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
                className={classes.modal}
                open={isOpen}
                onClose={handleClose}
                closeAfterTransition
                BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
                BackdropProps={{
                    timeout: 500,
                }}
            >
                <Fade in={isOpen}>
                    <div className={classes.paper + ' material-ui'}>
                        <div>
                            <h3>Confirmation Required</h3>
                            <div style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap'}}>
                                {message}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <TextField
                            label="XXX Name"
                            helperText={validationHelperText}
                            className={classes.textField}
                            value={InputtedXXX}
                            onChange={handleChange(setInputtedXXX)}
                            margin="normal"
                        />

                        <div className={'flex-space'} style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>
                            <Button className={classes.button} variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={ handleClose }>
                                CANCEL
                            </Button>

                            <Button className={classes.button} disabled={InputtedXXX === ''} variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={ validateAndExecuteFunction }>
                                CONFIRM
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Fade>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};

ConfirmationPopupValidateXXX.defaultProps = {
    validationHelperText: 'Type the XXX name to confirm creation',
};

ConfirmationPopupValidateXXX.prototypes = {
    selectedClient: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    setConfirmation: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    message: PropTypes.string,
    validationHelperText: PropTypes.string,
    executableFunction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    selectedClient: state.client.selectedClient,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setConfirmation })(ConfirmationPopupValidateXXX);
```

[image]

This is how I added the confirmation box to app.js

```
{ isConfirmationOpen &&
     <ConfirmationPopupValidateXXX
         isOpen={isConfirmationOpen}
         message={confirmationMessage}
         validationHelperText={confirmationValidationHelperText}
         executableFunction={confirmationExecutableFunction}
      />
}
```

```
await setConfirmation(true, msg, functionToExecute); // setConfirmation will dispatch this three variables to the store where ConfirmationPopupValidateXXX will use them


const functionToExecute = async () => {
   // call server
   // get response
   // useState - change component state add response Message so the client can see what is the response of the action he performed
};
```

Comment: Does it not work? The error sounds like its related to the dev tools, not the react app itself

Comment: true it was only a problem with the Redux Dev Tools. I disabled it and it works -_-